# How does Group by and Having works

Tags: sql, group-by

I am new to SQL and after writing some queries I wanted to understand how SQL "internally" processes the queries. I take one query from another post in stackoverflow:

```
select name from contacts
group by name
having count(*) > 1
```

My question is: group by name merges all rows with the same name into one row, how does then count know how many rows with the same name were merged. I am trying to split all steps in the processing of the query in order to understand how it is exactly working, but in this case it seems like you cannot split it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at execution plan in SSMS. There you can see aggregation step (group by), which results in two values per group - name itself and count of merged rows. Some steps after that (there can be some intermediate calculations) you can see filtering step, which excludes some rows (having).

Answer (score 1):

From your sql query that you show there
the execution sequence will be like this show below

```
from contacts
```

knowing which tables's data you are getting, next will be your `WHERE` clause but in this case you don't have one so will follow to the next step which is

```
group by name
```

group all the same name to a row of record.

*side note:* Now the `SELECT` statement still haven run yet, therefore when `HAVING` statement run can count the row that the same name has

Next is your

```
having count(*) > 1
```

filter up all the record which count more than 1, and lastly will be the `SELECT`

```
select name
```

above was the execute sequence for your example shown.

And these is the full sequence of sql query

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

Hope it help ya.

Comment: But this is exactly the problem, after group by you lose the information about how many records you merged (group by) and so in the having count(*) > 1 how do you know that?

Comment: SQL query actually smart when having a GROUP action, it will still saving the record for every row of record, but instead of showing them out it just store as visual data, therefore count(*) can be easily to get

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, it is also saving all the records although showing the result (grouped records). But where can I find this internal information, surely not in the documentation, so where then?