# How to filter on aggregation value in Athena (Presto)?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I can't run a simple sql select with where condition from Athena console. Below is the details:

```
SELECT name, count(*) AS c
FROM target_reddit_movie
GROUP BY name
HAVING c > 1
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I got an error `SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:74: Column 'c' cannot be resolved`.

It looks like Athena doesn't recognise the `as` column name. How can I make it work? Does it use a different syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is *logically* like this (execution engine is free to choose a different execution strategy):

1. `WHERE` is applied (if any; there is no `WHERE` in your case, of course)
2. `GROUP BY` aggregations are calculated
3. `HAVING` is applied on aggregated values -- here you can refer to aggregates (e.g. `count(*)`) and `GROUP BY` columns (e.g. `name` in your case)
4. `SELECT` assignments are applied (from now on `c` is known to mean `count(*)`)
5. `ORDER BY` is applied, hence it can use `c`
6. `LIMIT` is applied

See also [How does Group by and Having works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309769/how-does-group-by-and-having-works) and [Presto documentation for `SELECT`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html)

Comment: The explanation (as it stands now) is not correct. `HAVING` is applied after `GROUP BY` aggregation, so counting is already finished.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Oh, yes I am wrong. The `select` statement is executed after the `having` clause. Thanks.

Comment: "`select` statement is executed after the `having`" -- this is true, but can be easily misunderstood as "select expressions (like aggregations) are evaluated after rows are filtered with `having`". I expanded your explanation to hopefully be more explicit about this. Take a look if you agree with the edits I made.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, I agree with that!

Comment: what's the point of this answer? the OP's problem is resolved by replacing `HAVING c > 1` with `HAVING count(*) > 1`, he didn't ask to provide a sequence of keywords applied. I got the same issue, seems that Presto does not support using `HAVING` with aggregation alias

Comment: I got a lot out of this answer, thanks for laying it out this way. To @mangusta 's point, it's the difference between giving a person a fish and teaching them how to fish. This post is the latter.

Comment: @autonopy giving a fish and teaching how to fish are different questions and should be put into different topics